# Find points under the brushed region

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have customized the matrixscatterplot in d3 V4 to find the points that are under the brushed region for a particular cell.
Here is the plunkr for that

http://plnkr.co/edit/fL0C3XqvLtQO9SKWoV5c?p=preview

Now, for instance, if I brush a few points in any cell, the highlights are fine but I am getting a lot of data points in console.log  "selected points". (With the brushSelection extent logic in the brushend function, I have tried filtering  the data points and console log them )

Ideally, I want to get only those data points/ objects in the console that are under the brushed region for any cell.

Thanks. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
}

.axis,
.frame {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
  stroke: #ddd;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.cell text {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  fill: black;
}

.frame {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
}

circle {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

circle.hidden {
  fill: #ccc !important;
}

.extent {
  fill: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    size = 230,
    padding = 20;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .ticks(6);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(6);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

d3.csv("flowers.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var domainByTrait = {},
      traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "species"; }),
      n = traits.length;

  traits.forEach(function(trait) {
    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[trait]; });
  });

  xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
  yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

  var brush = d3.brush()
      .on("start", brushstart)
      .on("brush", brushmove)
      .on("end", brushend)
      .extent([[0,0],[size,size]]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", size * n + padding)
      .attr("height", size * n + padding)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

  svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
      .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)"; })
      .each(function(d) { x.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(xAxis); });

  svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
      .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * size + ")"; })
      .each(function(d) { y.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(yAxis); });

  var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
      .data(cross(traits, traits))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
      .each(plot);

  // Titles for the diagonal.
  cell.filter(function(d) { return d.i === d.j; }).append("text")
      .attr("x", padding)
      .attr("y", padding)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.x; });

  cell.call(brush);

  function plot(p) {
    var cell = d3.select(this);

    x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
    y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

    cell.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "frame")
        .attr("x", padding / 2)
        .attr("y", padding / 2)
        .attr("width", size - padding)
        .attr("height", size - padding);

    cell.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[p.x]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[p.y]); })
        .attr("r", 4)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); });
  }

  var brushCell;

  // Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
  function brushstart(p) {
    if (brushCell !== this) {
      d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.move, null);
      brushCell = this;
    x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
    y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
    }
  }

  // Highlight the selected circles.
  function brushmove(p) {
    var e = d3.brushSelection(this);
    //svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function(d) {
     d3.select(this).selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function(d) {
      return !e
        ? false
        : (
          e[0][0] > x(+d[p.x]) || x(+d[p.x]) > e[1][0]
          || e[0][1] > y(+d[p.y]) || y(+d[p.y]) > e[1][1]
        );
    });
  }

  // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
  function brushend(p) {  
    var e = d3.brushSelection(this);
    if (e === null) svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);

    var points = [];

     d3.select(this).selectAll("circle").filter(function(d){

      if (
          e[0][0] > x(+d[p.x]) || x(+d[p.x]) > e[1][0]
          || e[0][1] > y(+d[p.y]) || y(+d[p.y]) > e[1][1]
        )

        points.push(d);


     })

    console.log('selected points', points); 
  }
});

function cross(a, b) {
  var c = [], n = a.length, m = b.length, i, j;
  for (i = -1; ++i < n;) for (j = -1; ++j < m;) c.push({x: a[i], i: i, y: b[j], j: j});
  return c;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, `p.x` and `p.y` are not accessible inside the `brushend` function. But you can easily get the circle's positions with:

```
d3.select(this).attr("cx")
d3.select(this).attr("cy")
```

Besides that, the logic in the `if` is not correct, you should use `AND` to get the circles inside the 4 points:

```
if (
    e[0][0] < d3.select(this).attr("cx") && d3.select(this).attr("cx") < e[1][0] 
    && e[0][1] < d3.select(this).attr("cy") && d3.select(this).attr("cy") < e[1][1]
)
```

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/dA7qcvAhjZBsyqTsheYl?p=preview

Comment: I didn't see your answer before posting mine (as I was typing it). Anyway, hope the answers work for the OP.

Comment: Yea , it does work well for all the cells except for diagonal cells ( where points are alingned in a straight line ) , if you brush a few points in diagonal cells , it will show more number of selected points in console.

Comment: @Nicole No, it's showing the **correct** number. The thing is that, on those diagonal cells, you have a bunch of circles one over the other. You think that it's just one circle while in fact it's several! Inspect the elements and you'll see.

Comment: @Gerardo , Thanks for the clarification.This was the sample data, but the data that I am using is even more dense so got confused. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

**Minor change:**

The condition you're using in the `brushend` function (posted below) gets you the `hidden` class to the circles which you might wanna negate to get you the selected points.

Condition:

```
(
   e[0][0] > x(+d[p.x]) || x(+d[p.x]) > e[1][0]
      || e[0][1] > y(+d[p.y]) || y(+d[p.y]) > e[1][1]
)
```

Solution 1:
You can either negate the condition or change the symbols:

```
if (!(
    e[0][0] > x(+d[p.x]) || x(+d[p.x]) > e[1][0]
      || e[0][1] > y(+d[p.y]) || y(+d[p.y]) > e[1][1]
))
```

Solution 2 ( a better approach): You already are using the condition to add `hidden` class in the `brushmove`, you can just get the selected points based on that. Here:

```
d3.select(this).selectAll("circle").filter(function(d){

  if(!d3.select(this).classed('hidden'))

    points.push(d);

 })
```

Here's a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HpSZ5j21SfDrtNOncWCf?p=preview

Comment: Just like I mentioned for Gerardo's post ..  if you brush a few points in diagonal cells , it will show more number of selected points in console., besides your both methods are working well for non diagonal cells.

Comment: I just added a +1 to Gerardo's comment. Try changing the number of rows in *flowers.csv* to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I changed the data length and it is somewhat understandable.